# jQuery toggleClass not working - class not toggling

Tags: jquery, css

When I click on the link `Product`, I'm trying to toggle the class `hover` on the `span` element, so the down-arrow turns into an up-arrow.

Help appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mega-drop-down").click(function() {
    $(this).children('a span').toggleClass('hover');
    $('.mega-menu').not($(this).children('.mega-menu').toggle()).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.mega-menu {display: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
.mega-drop-down>a>span::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f107';
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.mega-drop-down>a>span.hover::after {
  content: '\f106';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Product</span></a>
  <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
    <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4 class="row mega-title">Instant Digital Signage Platform</h4>
          <ul class="cabeza">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a>
              <span class="mm-mm-subtext">See all the features packed into this powerful digital signage platform.</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Templates</a>
              <span class="mm-mm-subtext">1000’s of professionally designed templates for every business.</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The child of your child is not your child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) only selects direct descendants. You need to use [`$.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select multiple levels down.

```
$(this).find('a span').toggleClass('hover');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mega-drop-down").click(function() {
    $(this).find('a span').toggleClass('hover');
    $('.mega-menu').not($(this).children('.mega-menu').toggle()).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.mega-menu {display: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
.mega-drop-down>a>span::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f107';
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.mega-drop-down>a>span.hover::after {
  content: '\f106';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Product</span></a>
  <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
    <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4 class="row mega-title">Instant Digital Signage Platform</h4>
          <ul class="cabeza">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a>
              <span class="mm-mm-subtext">See all the features packed into this powerful digital signage platform.</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Templates</a>
              <span class="mm-mm-subtext">1000’s of professionally designed templates for every business.</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```